# Optimising a JOIN to the latest data in a second table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

We are having a problem optimising a set of queries that all follow the same pattern.

The basic scenario is that we have a table (`hours`) that records the weekly hours worked by an individual, against project codes.

We have a second table (`rates`) which records the historical hourly rates for each individual.

We want to report the total salary (`hours` * `rate`) for each project in the `hours` table

The query to return all the hours that we are interested in is

```
SELECT hours_job, SUM(hour_value) AS total_hours
FROM hours_table
WHERE hours_job_status = "1"
GROUP BY hours_job
```

We need to join that to the `rates` table, on the latest `rates_date`, however an individual may, in edge cases, have >1 rate on a particualr date, and in these cases we want the `MAX` rate

This is out current attempt, which is extremenly slow

```
SELECT hours_job, SUM(hour_value * rate_value) AS salary
FROM hours_table
JOIN rates_table ON rate_person_id = hours_person_id
WHERE hours_job_active = "1"
AND rate_date = (
  SELECT MAX(rate_date)
  FROM rates_table
  WHERE hours_person_id = rate_person_id
  AND hours_week >= rate_date
  AND rate_active = 1
)
AND rt_rate = (
  SELECT MAX(rate_value)
  FROM rates_table
  WHERE hours_person_id = rate_person_id
  AND hours_week >= rate_date
  AND rate_active = 1
GROUP BY hours_job
ORDER BY hours_job;
```

As suggested here are is a snippet of the data and expected result

**hours_table**

```
hours_id  hours_person_id  hours_week  hours_job  hours_value  hours_job_active
1  1  "2020-06-12"  100  20  1
2  1  "2020-06-12"  101  10  1
3  1  "2020-06-12"  102  10  1
4  2  "2020-06-12"  100  30  1
5  2  "2020-06-12"  102  10  1
```

**rates_table**

```
rate_id  rate_person_id  rate_date  rate_value  rate_type  rate_active
1  1  "2020-04-01"  25.00  A  1
2  1  "2019-04-01"  20.00  A  1
3  1  "2018-04-01"  18.00  A  1
4  2  "2020-04-01"  20.00  A  1 
5  2  "2020-04-01"  18.00  Y  1
```

Expected result would be

```
hours_job  salary
100  1100    ((20*25) + (30*20))
101  250     (10*25)
102  450     ((10*25) + (20*10))
```

Comment: Can you include in your question a few rows of sample data and the expected result?

Comment: We want to get all the entries in the `hours` table and join that dataset to the `MAX(rate_value)`, matching `hours_person_id` to `rate_person_id` where `rate_date` is bounded by the dates in the hours table...

Answer (score 1):

It's been long since I've had one of this problems to optimize, and without a test db I can't make sure this works, but have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT hours_job, SUM(hour_value * MAX(rate_value)) AS salary
FROM hours_table
JOIN rates_table ON rate_person_id = hours_person_id
WHERE hours_job_active = "1"
AND hours_week >= rate_date
AND rate_active = 1
GROUP BY hours_job, rates_date
ORDER BY hours_job;
```

Comment: That seems to produce multiple entries for each row - if I include an hours column as well as salary the hours is multiplied by the number or rates.